# Is it possible to make a certain domain endpoint display the contents of another folder?

Tags: domain, subdomain, folder-redirection

I'm not too sure how to ask this question properly, as I have no idea if it can be done.

I have a domain that powers a website built with a CMS. However, for certain performance and sustainability reasons, I will be changing it for a custom solution. My question is the following:

Take, for example, `https://example.com/products/a-certain-product` as a page on the current website and `https://subdomain.example.com/products/a-certain-product` as the location of the new page with the custom solution.

Would it be possible to make the current page display the contents of the new one without redirecting or changing the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming here that you control the [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)
of both servers.

The simplest solution would be to make the DNS reference to the old website to
return the IP address of the new one. Any DNS change may need a few hours 
to fully propagate.

Comment: could this be done on a per-page basis? Or would it necessarily affect the whole site at once?

Comment: This affects the whole website. A per-webpage solution would require redirection, either in the application or in the web-server software (Apache/Linux or IIS/Windows).